# How do you make negative values positive using absolutes?

Tags: python, list, absolute

```
list_1 = [ 10, 20, 40, -19, -4, 30]

desired output = [ 0, 0, 0, 19, 4, 0]
```

I have a list with a lot of values, some positive and some negative. What is the best methodology to changing the values in the list that are negative into the positive? Next, what is the best methodolgy for changing the positive values to 0?

I feel like it is simple but am getting stuck

Comment: Neither `list 1` nor `desired output` are valid variable name. Start by writing valid synatx

Comment: You're asking two questions, when you should only be asking one question per post, and also you're asking for the "best way" which is entirely subjective. According to [ask], you need to have one question per post, and ask objective questions.

Answer (score 3):

Basic list comprehension should do the trick:

```
[-min(x, 0) for x in list_1]
```

The rationale is that

1. you want to take `min(x, 0)` for each element `x` in the list. This will change all the positive numbers to 0 while leaving the negative numbers unchanged.
2. you can then take the negative of the resulting value from step 1 to make the negative numbers positive. Since the positive numbers were already changed to 0, these will stay 0.

For example, if `x=5`, `-min(x, 0)` will be `0`. If `x=-5`, `-min(x, 0)` will be `5`.

Comment: + for a solution that works, - for a solution that OP will not understand.

Comment: @ThomasWeller added rationale/clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Quite Pythonic and readable to use a list comprehension and `if` expression here:

```
>>> input = [10, 20, 40, -19, -4, 30]
>>> [-x if x < 0 else 0 for x in input]
[0, 0, 0, 19, 4, 0]
```

Comment: + for a solution that works, - for a solution that OP will not understand.

Comment: @ThomasWeller why would OP not understand?

Comment: They can't even define a variable nor write a for loop with an if condition themselves. How shall they understand list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

A solution without list comprehension.

```python
list_1 = [ 10, 20, 40, -19, -4, 30]
desired_list = []

for i in list_1:
    if i < 0:
        desired_list.append(-i)
    else:
        desired_list.append(0)
```

In this for-loop, we check for every element in `list_1`, if it is less than `0`, then the sign is changed. If not, then a `0` is appended to the `desired_list`.

Output:

```
>>> desired_list
[0, 0, 0, 19, 4, 0]
```

Comment: List comprehension is the natural pythonic way to do it though...